# how can i add filesaver.js to gulp

Tags: angularjs, filesaver.js

I am trying to manage my app which is a spa angular using gulp. Now i have a problem with FileSaver . My app requires me to download some files. 
I use the following code for the same

```
$window.saveAs(response.response,downloadFile);
```

When I check the response i am getting the file in blob form. But the debugger doesnt go past save as function. I think FileSaver.js file is not getting recognised. I have added both blob.js and fileSaver.js in the vendor.js n I can see them too. But only blob.js works . I am using this http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js
What should i do?

Comment: doesn't `$window.saveAs` opens a dialog that takes yes/no from the user?

Comment: not in chrome atleast. But even if it does will that cause a problem?

Comment: gulp runs in backend. $window.saveAs is a browser api.. how are you mixing client side and server side apis?

Comment: i am using gulp only for minifying purposes